# c++ tcp multithreaded client/server - how to communicate with threaded sockethandler?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, udp

I made a multi-threaded client/server in c++. It works fine. The 'protocol' is text based. I have a sockethandler function (that runs threaded in an infinite loop until something happens with the connection or the client gracefully disconnects) after that thread starts the server is waiting for a new connection. Now, for this specific program I'll only allow one client at a time. Up until now the client has always been the initiator and the server responds. But I need to send the client program lots of data (not size, frequency) from other threads and I don't know how. My code is cross platform - I compile for windows and linux from the same source. The client/server code is cross platform too give or take a few lines... What's the best method to do this? queues? or are there faster methods? can someone point me in the right direction or give me some example code please?
I did try to sort it out and design-wise I'm considering adding an udp listener to the client and an udp sender to the server so that I have 2 communication channels but I don't know if that a good practice...
I currently have a socket in a thread but I only know how to use it from one direction - that's my main issue...

Comment: yes but the server needs to send data to the client - data that the client never asked for at any given time - fast - I can't have my client polling all the time...

Comment: A server cannot send data to an unexistent client. In order to be able as a server to send data to somebody, the client should open at first the channel and in order to be able as a client to receive data that channel must be open forever. If instead you don't like the server client model than that is a different approach.

Comment: In case you opt for a different approach than any end, may send data at any time using udp communication. So any end should be able to receive and send communication from unexpected parties.

Comment: but how do I communicate efficiently with the threaded code where the socket resides? That's my main issue. I just need to be able to tell the thread I have data to send to the client. I was thinking about a queue to put messages in and have the thread poll for data. I've never done any coding like this... I know the queue will work but if it's a good practice I don't know . I'm hoping someone could point me to a good design

Comment: You haven't to communicate at all with the thread that opened the socket. You only have to know the global variable accessible from all threads that holds the socket. Now that the socket is opened, you must take care to lock it, and send the data you want, afterwards unlock it. By locking unlocking I mean using a compare_exchange_strong instruction.

Comment: Regarding the locking unlocking, you must use a global variable accessed as a semaphore

Comment: Ok - I managed to use the socket using your instructions. thank you

Comment: The problem stated was completely clear, and I am happy I helped to simplify the solution. What I don't understand is why they put on hold a so clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> design-wise I'm considering adding an udp listener to the client and
>   an udp sender to the server so that I have 2 communication channels
>   but I don't know if that a good practice...

The main problem you're likely to run into there (outside of the usual UDP problems involving dropped packets) is that often the client machine will be running a firewall that blocks all incoming UDP packets.  If that's the case, you'd need to instruct the user to either disable the firewall or add rules to the firewall to allow incoming UDP packets on the port you are using (which may or may not be a reasonable request, depending on who your users are, but will definitely be a hassle).

Given that, it would probably be better if you could have the client connect to the server via TCP, as usual, and send the data the client needs back to the client over that same TCP connection you're already using.  That way firewall issues are avoided.

> The client/server code is cross platform too give or take a few
>   lines... What's the best method to do this? queues? or are there
>   faster methods? can someone point me in the right direction or give me
>   some example code please?

Since in the comments you indicated that your main problem is cross-thread communications, here is the way I handle that in my multi-threaded programs:

1. Each of my threads uses non-blocking I/O and an event loop that centers around a blocking call to select().  The idea is that the only place the thread should ever block is in the select() call, and the select() call should return only when there is some more work for the thread to do.
2. In order for thread A to send a message to thread B, thread A must do the following:

   a. Lock the mutex that is guarding thread B's incoming-Messages-queue
    b. Append the message to the end of thread B's incoming-Messages-queue
    c. Unlock the mutex that is guarding thread B's incoming-Messages-queue
    d. Signal thread B so that thread B will wake up and check its incoming-Messages-queue for new messages
3. All of the above is straightforward except for part (d) -- getting thread B to wake up reliably.  To do that, I have created (at startup) a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) or [socket-pair](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketpair.2.html) that thread A can send to and that thread B can select() on.  So as part of (d), thread A writes a byte to the socket at its end of the pipe (or socketpair), and that causes thread B's socket to select() as ready-for-read.  When thread B sees that, it reads the byte(s) from the socket (non-blocking read of course), throws them away, then locks its incoming-Messages-queue, grabs all the Messages out of that queue, unlocks again, then processes the grabbed Messages in order.

Note that in order to keep things efficient, you'll probably want to make your Message objects as zero-copy as possible, especially if they are going to be containing large amounts of data.  You can do that using shared_ptr or similar so that the only things you are adding to the queue are the relatively small shared_ptr objects, not the larger Message/data that they point to.  Using smart pointers also ensures that the Messages/data won't get memory-leaked.

This sort of thing might work with blocking I/O as well, except that if you use blocking I/O you won't have any guarantees about how long a thread will take to respond to a message you sent it -- in particular if there is a network problem, then a thread's call to send() on a TCP socket might not return for multiple minutes, and there's not much you can do about it -- and of course a call to recv() might block forever if there is no data arriving from the client.  That's why I always use non-blocking I/O if possible.

Comment: Note that Windows doesn't have socketpair() built in but it's not difficult to roll your own implementation of socketpair() for use when compiling under Windows... google "Windows socketpair" for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

When a client is connected to the server, I suppose that in the Server you have an in and out file. So if you need only one shared communication channel with your client accessible from various tasks in your server, you should have a task that receives communication and opens the communication channels ( doing the housekeeping ). Afterwards you may use that "shared resource" as a global variable from each thread by using locks in order to impede corruption.